# laravel model controller retrieve data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

I'am new to laravel and had a hard time for eloquent ORM, I like to retrieve `Favourite` items from the table with specific user id, but seem I don't find a way to display the data correctly.

I refer and copied the favourite model code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22913605/laravel-orm-user-can-favorite-multiple-models)

Model: Favourite

```
class Favourite extends BaseModel
{
    public function favouritable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Model: Course

```
public function favourites()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Favourite::class, 'favouritable');
}


public function myFavourite()
{
    return $this->favourites()->where('favor_user', '=', auth()->user()->id);
}
```

Controller: FavouriteController@index

```
public function index()
{
    $course = new Course();
    $myfavs = $course->myFavourite();

    //dd($myfavs);

    $this->vdata(compact('myfavs'));

    return view('front.favorites', $this->vdata);
}
```

In blade view, but return empty/blank data:

```
@foreach($myfavs as $myfav)
    {{ $myfav->$course_name }}
@endforeach
```

When i `dd($myfavs)` it display pretty bunches of data that i couldn't find the data that is stored in the favourites table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have added the conditions but forgot get the results with one of the methods to do so.

Try :

```
$myfavs = $course->myFavourite()->get();
```

Or :

```
$myfavs = $course->myFavourite()->take(<N>)->get;
```

Or

```
::all()
```

etc. take a look at : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-models